# Use 'Stuff' variable in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

So here is the query code we are using:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATE, Nominations.Nomination_Date_Created) AS Nomination_Date_Created, 
    Nominations.Nomination_Status,  
    (CASE 
        WHEN MIN(EPORT.dbo.FDA_Divisions.division_name) = MAX(EPORT.dbo.FDA_Divisions.division_name) 
           THEN MIN(EPORT.dbo.FDA_Divisions.division_name) 
           ELSE 'Multiple Divisions' 
     END) AS Employee_Division, 
    Nominations.Nomination_Awarded_For, 
    Nominations.Nomination_Awarded_Other, 
    Nom.First_Name + ' ' + Nom.Last_Name AS Nominator_Name, 
    Nominations.Nomination_Group_UUID, 
    Nominations.Nomination_Group_Name, 
    Nominations.Nomination_Group_Time_off_Sum, 
    Nominations.Nomination_Group_Cash_Sum, 
    Nominations.Nomination_Type, 
    Nominations.Nomination_Identifier, Nominations.Nomination_Employee_UUID, 
    Nominations.Nomination_Nominator_ID, Nominations.Nomination_NOAC,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + NOMGroup.division_name  
           FROM vw_group_nomination_divisions NOMGroup
           WHERE NOMGroup.Nomination_Group_UUID = Nominations.Nomination_Group_UUID
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') divList          
FROM             
    Nominations 
INNER JOIN
    ePort.dbo.Employees AS Employees_1 ON Employees_1.CapHR_ID = Nominations.Nomination_Employee_CapHR_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ePort.dbo.FDA_Offices ON Employees_1.office_id = ePort.dbo.FDA_Offices.office_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ePort.dbo.FDA_Centers ON Employees_1.center_ID = ePort.dbo.FDA_Centers.Center_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ePort.dbo.FDA_Divisions ON Employees_1.division_id = ePort.dbo.FDA_Divisions.division_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ePort.dbo.Employees AS Nom ON Nominations.Nomination_Nominator_ID = Nom.CapHR_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ePort.dbo.Employees AS NomAppRTO ON Nominations.Nomination_Approving_Officer_NED_ID = NomAppRTO.CapHR_ID
GROUP BY 
    CONVERT(DATE, Nominations.Nomination_Date_Created), 
    Nominations.Nomination_Awarded_For, Nominations.Nomination_Status, 
    Nominations.Nomination_Awarded_Other, 
    Nom.First_Name + ' ' + Nom.Last_Name, 
    Nominations.Nomination_Type, Nominations.Nomination_Group_UUID, 
    Nominations.Nomination_Group_Name, 
    Nominations.Nomination_Group_Time_off_Sum, 
    Nominations.Nomination_Group_Cash_Sum, 
    Nominations.Nomination_Identifier, Nominations.Nomination_Type, 
    Nominations.Nomination_Employee_UUID, 
    Nominations.Nomination_Nominator_ID, Nominations.Nomination_NOAC
HAVING        
    (Nominations.Nomination_Type = 'Group') 
    AND (YEAR(CONVERT(DATE, Nominations.Nomination_Date_Created)) IN ('2020')) 
ORDER BY 
    Nomination_Date_Created DESC, Nominations.Nomination_Group_UUID
```

Output:

```
| Id                                   | divList           |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------+
| 3462BF9B-5056-9C58-994BFFC6A38E7368  | DLR, DTD, OHCM    |
| 3B8202C2-5056-9C58-99C591AA86B3A1C9  | OHCM              |
| CB5A722C-5056-9C58-9983C1F6C66C0AD7  | DTD, STMD         |
```

And the output is how we need it, however, we need to be able to search it and we cannot get that working. So how does one reference the column 'Name' that the Stuff function creates in the WHERE clause of the query?

We need to do a search within the HAVING OR WHERE clause for a value within the 'divList' column if possible. Such as divList IN ('OHCM').

Anytime I reference 'divList', I get the error:
**Invalid column name 'divList'.**

This would filter the results to records 1 and 2.

I hope that better explains it.

Comment: "WHERE [Name] IN ('ccc')" doesn't make any sense in this context. What is the output you actually want? Just rows 1 and 3? Or just rows 1 and 3 with the value of the "Name" column being only 'ccc'? I honestly cannot tell what you want here.

Comment: Correct, with the WHERE clause I would expect to only see rows 1 and 3. Sorry if I am confusing.

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired result clearly.

Comment: Sample data ans query provided. Thank you and sorry if I didn't make sense.

Comment: Since those two conditions you have in the `HAVING` clause aren't operating on any **aggregates** of columns, those really should be in the `WHERE` clause instead

Answer (score 4):

You don't want the string.  Use more basic logic instead:

```
having sum(case when division_name = 'ccc' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but I'm still getting the same error:
Invalid column name 'Name'.

Comment: Probably a consequence of aliasing the column twice: `... abc = ... AS Name ...`.

Comment: Sorry, that was NOT in my code. Updated code, I hope that helps!

Comment: @DavidJacobson . . . I didn't make up `name`; it was in the original question that you asked.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, I know that, I added it in the query and I'm trying to use that 'column name' to search within. I update the query to the actual query and the STUFF column is 'divList'. I need to search wihtin that column. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How is your temp table associated with the view. You need to join your temp table with the nominations view.

```
SELECT ID,
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + NOMGroup.division_name  
       FROM vw_group_nomination_divisions NOMGroup
       WHERE NOMGroup.Nomination_Group_UUID = nom.Nomination_Group_UUID
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') Name
FROM temp1
JOIN vw_group_nomination_divisions nom ON temp1.ID = nom.ID
WHERE Nominations.[Name] = 'ccc'
GROUP by ID
```

Comment: Sorry Varun, you're correct. I updated the code as it should be.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data as well.

Comment: I added some data in the question. Did you need more data?